# Is it possible to set a non primary key as foreign key in another table?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

More specifically, I would like to set the `Email` column from `AspNetUsers` table as foreign key in another table.

I hope to have explained my problem well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes and No

#### SQL Server, specifically:

If you're just asking about SQL Server (and *not* Entity Framework), then I *quoteth* [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15):

> A foreign key constraint doesn't have to be linked only to a primary key constraint in another table. Foreign keys can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

Therefore to answer your stated question directly:

- *Is it possible to set a non primary key as foreign key in another table?*

  - If they're "normal" columns, then no, because otherwise SQL Server has no way of knowing that those values will uniquely identify each row.
  - But if the columns are in either in a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or have a **non-filtered** `UNIQUE INDEX` applied to them, then *yes*, you can.
  - This requires SQL Server 2005 or later. (I might be wrong, but I don't believe SQL Server 2000 supported `FOREIGN KEY` constraint columns referencing `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` columns.

[There are subtle differences between `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE INDEX`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index), though the main difference is *indicating intent* - so you should prefer `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` over `UNIQUE INDEX` when you're using a column - or columns - as a *secondary key*.

#### Entity Framework

- **Entity Framework 6**:

  - I'll admit I'm unsure. I remember having to really fight EF6 and use workarounds like `VIEW`s to make EF6 play-nice with FK references to `UNIQUE KEY` constraints, but some reports suggest that modern versions of EF6 *do* support this natively.
- **Entity Framework Core**:

  - Yes. Use `HasPrincipal()` with `HasForeignKey()` to define both a secondary-key on `TPrincipal` and the foreign-key on `TDependant` that points to that secondary-key.

---

As for your scenario, specifically: `dbo.AspNetUsers`:

Assuming that you want to use the `Email` column to uniquely identify users, then I recommend that you *don't do that*: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to use mutable data (i.e. data that can change) as a key. Keys must be unique and ideally should be immutable - and while an e-mail address can be unique in some contexts (e.g. your system won't allow multiple users to share the same e-mail address) they aren't immutable (users *can and do* change e-mail addressees).

Another caveat: in order to use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE INDEX` as a foreign-key target then those column(s) **cannot be filtered** or have `NULL`s - but `dbo.AspNetUser.Email` is `nvarchar(256) NULL`, so you'll need to ensure all users have distinct email addresses set *first*.

Having said that, this will work:

```
-- 1. Change `Email` from `NULL` to a `NOT NULL` column, as `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` columns cannot contain duplicates or nulls:
ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers
    ALTER COLUMN [Email] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL;

-- 2. Create a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT over the `Email` column, so SQL Server knows every row has a distinct value in that column:
ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Email UNIQUE ( Email );

-- 3. Create a new table with a FOREIGN KEY in the other table:
CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable (
    Etc       nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    UserEmail nvarchar(256) NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT FK_Users_by_email FOREIGN KEY ( UserEmail ) REFERENCES dbo.AspNetUsers ( [Email] )
);
```

Comment: @GurV I made the assumption that because the OP mentioned `AspNetUsers` they're using SQL Server - though I appreciate ASP.NET Identity is available for other DB systems too.

Comment: It's rather EF limitation than SQL Server. For instance alternate (unique) keys and FK referencing them are perfectly supported by EF Core.

Comment: i was able to create a foreign key to a non-pk column. no issues.

Comment: @DeniseMichelledelBando With the exception of `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE INDEX` columns that shouldn't be possible. Can you reproduce it in SqlFiddle and share your results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can make foreign key by principal key in asp.net core, by using fluent api. You can see an example from microsoft doc from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#principal-key)

Comment: Your answer refers to using or defining an _unenforced_ foreign-key constraint in Entity Framework, not in SQL directly - so while EF will respect the imaginary constraint, other programs and raw SQL won't - and that's assuming the built-in DDL code generation in EF won't complain about using a feature unsupported by the current backing-store.

Comment: I fist made the principal column as unique and then added the foreign key and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help. +1

Answer (score -1):

i was able to create a foreign key to a non-pk column. no issues.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[fldKey] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[t1] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_t2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_t2_t1] FOREIGN 
KEY([t1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[t1] ([fldKey])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_t2_t1]
GO
```

Comment: When I run this SQL I get these errors: "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.t1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_t2_t1'.", "Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.".